# Custom Journey Activity - Get data extension field names

Tags: marketing-cloud, javascript, journeybuilder

We have built a custom journey activity - we need to display the fields of a data extension in the UI. When the load the UI in the journey builder we request the requesttoken event and the marketing cloud journey builder in turn fires the OnrequestedToken event which gives us the Fuel2 token and the legacy token - along with the end point we can call. We have successfully used this to query a DE for a particular value (/data/v1/customobjectdata/key/relay_network_metadata/rowset) - however i cannot figure out the end point to query a data extension for its column name.

Any help would be appreciated.

Regards
Sid

Comment: You would need to use SOAP https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/retrieving_dataextension_object.htm

Comment: Thanks @EazyE - i figured out - will post the answer

Comment: @SiddharthKumar : Could you please share your findings so that its helpful to others